# Having trouble moving symlinks from backup to boot partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, symbolic-link, cp

### The context

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu (Jammy Jellfish)/Windows laptop ([Dell XPS 9550](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/xps-15-9550-laptop/overview)).  My `/boot` partition was too small to support an update, so I used GParted to attempt to resize it.  However, I ran into a [GParted bug around resizing FAT partitions](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649324), so instead used the workaround approach of deleting the partition, formatting it as Ext4, resizing it, and then reformatting it as FAT and restoring my `/boot` files from a backup.

### The problem

Here's where the problem occurs: every time I try to restore my files from the backup, there are four files:

- `vmlinuz`
- `initrd.img.old`
- `vmlinuz.old`
- `initrd.img`

...that return the error `cp: cannot create symbolic link '/mnt/new_boot/./<FILE_NAME>': Operation not permitted`.

I'm wondering what the best approach is to move forward.  I assume I cannot expect my system to boot without these files.  Is there a way to successfully copy them over?  If not, is it safe to create new symlinks with the same names, pointing to the relevant versions of `vmlinuz-VERSION-generic` and `initrd.img-VERSION-generic`?  If I take that approach, what permissions do those files require?  Or is it better to somehow restore from a Ubuntu Live USB?  I'm a bit out of my depth here; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Two things ... One is strange: `/boot` partition on FAT ... And the other is a fact: FAT doesn't support symbolic links ... Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Raffa - yes, I was starting to notice the same thing as I was trying to create my own symlinks based on [Jos's advice below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1469404/651576).  However, I just verified from previous screenshots I took before formatting that the boot partition _was_ previously formatted FAT32, and contained symlinks, and was happily booting into GRUB as expected before I started down this path.  So, I'm not sure what's going on with that...

Comment: How big was that partition's size before you resize it?

Comment: `99MB`, which I subsequently sized up to `499MB`.

Comment: There is a slim possibility that you were looking at not `/boot` but rather `/boot/efi` which is actually akin to the FAT family but totally different in function from `/boot` which should be an EXT* family filesystem ... Might this be the case?

Comment: @Raffa-- on review, this is 100% the case (－‸ლ) I've always mounted it at `/boot` when swapping Linux installs so I got confused.  As you can see I'm out of my area of knowledge by quite a bit.  Would you be able to point me to the appropriate resources for troubleshooting now that we know I've mismatched partition types?

Comment: Is your boot partition/directory intact? if yes, then recreate the EFI partition https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394708/accidentally-deleted-efi-partition-system-is-still-running and you should be good to go ... You can do that from a live USB as well.

Comment: How exactly did you create the backup, how exactly do you try to restore it? Please add this information to the question.

Comment: I was under the impression that we were talking about a system that was restored from backup. Obviously a Linux `/boot` partition can't be formatted as FAT32. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: @Jos — might still be useful for visitors to the post.  Although given that I was on the wrong path all along I might delete the question.  I'll probably wait until I actually resolve the issue to determine whether or not there is anything useful I can contribute to the site, or if it is just cruft that should be removed.  Thanks for weighing in, either way!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the links yourself as root.

Being links, they will automatically have the correct permission `lrwxrwxrwx`. There is no reason this approach shouldn't work.